# Move raid hard drive to a different server

Tags: backup, raid1, ibm-xseries, safe-remove

I have a RAID 1 system for my IBM x3550 m4 that had suddenly failed. (system board problem). While waiting for the technical support from IBM, I really need to get the data from that server so I can transfer it to a temporary server. Since RAID 1 is a duplicate of 2 HDD, my question is, is it possible to move that 1 Hard drive from the failed server and insert it to a same IBM x3550 m4 just to get/backup the data that I needed? (without losing any data from both)

Answer (score 1):

If your temporary server is the same hardware, with the same RAID card, then check with your support if you can simply replace the disks in the new machine.

If not, I would definitely wait for IBM to replace the failed system board.

Comment: Sorry i haven't responded in this issue. What i did was transfer the raid controller and the hard disks on the temp server (with same specs) and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this is possible, but I have no experience with that particular RAID controller. Normally, the meta data is stored on the drive, so inserting it in another server should work. You can immediately accompany it with an empty disk, and it may even sync it for you.

I would ask IBM support, though.

Also remember that your network MAC address will change, and this may affect DHCP leases, interfaces names (linux udev), etc.

Comment: What i did was transfer the raid controller and the hard disks on the temp server (with same specs) and that worked. i am actually planning to use it as the permanent server without transferring back the controller and the HDDs. Will that be okay?

Comment: @Faye if the server works now and you want to keep using it, then yes, it will be OK, right?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to keep it that way.